# How to load .env vars when running node.js command line application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I created a small application using node.js and express but wanted to convert part of it's functionality into a command line tool.

When I run the application from the command line the .env file doesn't seem to be loading with the variables, and instead return `undefined` e.g. `const token = process.env.TOKEN;`

However if I run the application by starting up the server it will inject those variables as normal.

I don't want to pass them along in the command line as args

Is there any way to ensure environment variables are injected?

I've used `npm install -g .` to install the application and ran it from the command line. The values are defined when I start up the application using `ts-node`. I feel like this is something to do with the order of executions when loading the app.

my package json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "spotifybpmsort",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "bin": "./src/index.ts",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/yargs": "^17.0.17",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "yargs": "^17.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you call `config` from `doting`?

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry could you explain how to do this?

Comment: You should call dotenv.config() at the beginning of your file.

Comment: "*When I run the application from the command line*" - well are you running it by using [`env-cmd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd), like you do when starting your server, or not?

Comment: @PaulSerre thanks Paul that did the trick, I thought `dotenv` was replaceable by `env-cmd` since it worked initially without having `dotenv` package. I installed dot-env and called the config which worked. I had to do this in every file an env var was required though.

Comment: @Sam I'm glad you made it work